# Mypy thinks @classmethod @property is Callable

Tags: python, mypy, callable

Mypy seems to have trouble understanding a property is not a callable method of a class:

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Type


class A:
    pass


class B:
    @abstractmethod
    @property
    @classmethod
    def other_type(cls) -> Type[A]:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        assert issubclass(cls.other_type, A)
```

Running mypy on the above example results in the following error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "issubclass" has incompatible type "Callable[[], Type[A]]"; expected "type"  [arg-type]
```

How can I enforce the correct type, without `# type: ignore[arg-type]`? I'm using mypy version 0.782 and python 3.7

(Note: I'm running mypy with the `--check-untyped-defs` flag, so mypy should be scanning the `__init_subclass__` method).

Comment: I don't see an error running this in the [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.780&python=3.7)

Comment: indeed i wouldn't expect to see one as `__init_subclass__` is untyped and my memory is that mypy doesn't check untyped methods

Comment: @joel I updated the question (I use the `--check-untyped-defs` flag)

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're trying is even valid before Python 3.9, but regardless there is an issue open on mypy about this https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11619